# Array map use variable to identify column to return

Tags: php, array-map

I am trying to use array map dynamically, the column in the array may change so I don't want to specify it using string but want to use a variable to specify it, it does not work. Tried all the following combinations, it returns null.

```
$column = 'MANAGER_GROUP';
array_map(function($el){ return $el['"'.$column.'"']; }, $dbData);
array_map(function($el){ return $el["$column"]; }, $dbData);
array_map(function($el){ return $el[$column]; }, $dbData);

//this works though
array_map(function($el){ return $el["MANGER_GROUP"]; }, $dbData);
```

Comment: You have to use the keyword "use" in php To access variables outside your Closure function which in your case the Callback Function.. see the answer Below by Tadas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous function has it's own scope, it does not have access to parent scope automatically. You have to explicitly specify a variable to be passed to anonymous function context.

```
$column = 'MANAGER_GROUP';
array_map(function($el) use ($column) { 
    return $el[$column];
}, $dbData);
```